# Good way to connect parent table/entity with child table/entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Currently, I'm using Entity Framework and have two database tables, one "parent" table and one "child" table to store language-dependent strings:

[image]

I want to "intelligent" get a list of all elements and their child elements following this "algorithm":

> 1. Get the child element for language A.
> 2. If not available, get the child element for language B.

(The fallback language B is always present).

The result would look something like this:

[image]

I.e. for item 4 there is no entry in language "DE" (German), so the fallback to language "EN" (English) takes place.

When only relying on *one* language, I could use this code:

```
using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
{
    var items =
        ctx.Items.Select(
        i =>
            new ItemModel
            {
                Id = i.Id,
                Name = i.ChildItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Language == "DE").Name
            });
}
```

Since I have to take care of a fallback language, too, the only thing I could think of is using a `foreach` loop.

Ideally, I would want to avoid this and use one single LINQ statement, similar to the one above.

**So my question is:**

Can I express my "algorithm" in a single LINQ statement?

Comment: `Name = iChildItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Language == "DE" || x.Language == "EN").Name`?

Comment: @Dennis Wouldn't your approach select "EN", even if there _is_ a "DE" present (depending on sort order?)

Comment: It would be a very strange behavior. Condition will be translated into something like `[ExtentN].[Language] = N'DE' OR [ExtentN].[Language] = N'EN'`. I don't think, that any SQL implementation uses complete boolean expression evaluation (at least, by default). But I'm not sure, that's why this is a commentary.

Comment: What about using custom `OrderByDescending`? something like `OrderByDescending(x => x.Language == currentLanguage ? 2 : (x.Language == defaultLanguage) ? 1 : 0).FirstOrDefault()`. So if it matches current language, it has weight of 2, if matches default language it has weight of 1 and all others have 0 weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do something like this, suppose you have a list of languages ordered by priority:

```
var languages = new List<string> {"DE", "EN", "FR"};//Can add more
using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
{
  var items =
    ctx.Items.Select(
        i => new ItemModel
        {
            Id = i.Id,
            Name = languages.Select(lang=> i.ChildItems
                                            .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Language == lang))
                            .FirstOrDefault(x=>x!=null).Name;//Suppose the default value of ChildItem is null (a reference type).
        });
}
```

or this:

```
using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
{
  var items =
    ctx.Items.Select(
        i => new ItemModel
        {
            Id = i.Id,
            Name = i.ChildItems.FirstOrDefault(x=>languages.Any(k=>k == x.Language)).Name                 
        });
}
```